# ARM Cortex R5 exception triggered by assembly stm r12,{r1,r4,r7} instruction

Tags: arm, reset

Strange problem while executing r12,{r1,r4,r7} , hex code E88C 0092, binary 1110 1000 1000 1100 0000 0000 1001 0010‬. The microcontroller triggers an exception and stops. This happens inside a normal function, no concurrency or race conditions are involved. Tons of optimization with mingw for arm though. Cortex R5. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: countless possibilities but first that is not an instruction.  is it an unaligned access.  it is a cortex-r did you have a security or other cortex-r specific exception.  What exception and what other information within the exception handler are you seeing to indicate what happened?  The answer to what happened is there, you need to extract it.

Comment: e88c0092  stm r12, {r1, r4, r7}

Comment: What is the content of r12 when this happens? You might be attempting to write to the memory addresses to which you are not allowed to write, etc.